# Nullable type throws error "Must be an instance of Exception"

Tags: php, laravel

After adding `?string` type to the function paramerers it throws me an error.

Error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Whoops\Exception\Inspector::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Exception, instance of ParseError given, called in
>   /var/www/website/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Exception/Inspector.php
>   on line 80

Code:

```
public function getPayments(?string $searchKey = '', $searchByColumn = "id")
{
     return $this->model->where($searchByColumn, '=', $searchKey)->get();
}
```

I am using laravel4 with php7. What can I do about it?

Comment: [Nullable types weren't introduced until PHP 7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types). If you're getting a parse error, you're probably using 7.0.

Comment: If you upgrade to 7.1, you may encounter other issues, though. Google "Laravel 4 PHP 7.1 support" and you'll see a few things.